# How can I install npm packages when I have a failed network request error?

Tags: node.js, npm-install

I'm using a Mac with the zsh terminal, and I have node v16.13.1 on my machine.
I'm trying to install packages, but I haven't been successful. I get the error below, regardless of what package I try to install. I've also tried initializing first using npm -init, but I still get the same result.

```
npm ERR! code ECONNRESET
npm ERR! errno ECONNRESET
npm ERR! network request to https://registry.npmjs.org/figlet failed, reason: Client network socket disconnected before secure TLS connection was established
npm ERR! network This is a problem related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network 
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/edgaracuna/.npm/_logs/2022-01-02T16_01_32_283Z-debug.log
```

How can I resolve this issue to be able to install node packages?

Comment: You can often just get them from their repo; it's just files. When npm is down, npm is down. (You can also check your network settings, or just wait, or set up a local npm for caching--which doesn't help for *new* dependencies.)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score -1):

I was unable to recreate the issue, so I think this isn't a problem that you can directly solve. Either you have a firewall issue, or maybe the npm servers were down or broken at the time. Just try again later, reboot your computer or join a different wifi network.